# Is there any reason why my results are the same for the most informative feature for binary classification?

Tags: python, binary, classification, feature-extraction

Below is the codes to extract most informative feature for binary classification 
for each classes:

```
def most_informative_feature_for_binary_classification(vectorizer, classifier, n=100):
    """
    Identify most important features if given a vectorizer and binary classifier.
    Set n to the number of weighted features you would like to show.
    """
    def read_counter():
        return loads(open("counter.json", "r").read()) + 1 if path.exists("counter.json") else 0

    def write_counter():
        with open("counter.json", "w") as f:
            f.write(dumps(counter))

    counter = 1

    counter = read_counter()
    atexit.register(write_counter)
    if counter >= 7:
        counter = 0

    # additional stopwords to be remove
    # Open a file and read it into memory
    file = open('..\stopwords.txt')
    additional_stopwords = file.read()
    additional_stopwords = additional_stopwords.split()

    class_labels = classifier.classes_
    feature_names = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
    feature_names = [word for word in feature_names if word not in additional_stopwords]

    topn_class1 = sorted(zip(classifier.coef_[0], feature_names))[:n]
    topn_class2 = sorted(zip(classifier.coef_[0], feature_names))[-n:]

    # class_labels = category
    # coef = co-effecient
    # feat = most informative feature
    if 1 <= counter <= 6:
        for coef, feat in topn_class1:
            print(class_labels[counter - 1], coef, feat)
            # print(class_labels)
            # -> output: [2 3 4 5 6 7 8] index of this 0 1 2 3 4 5 6

        print()

        for coef, feat in reversed(topn_class2):
            print(class_labels[counter], coef, feat)

    else:
        print("=== PLEASE RUN PROGRAM AGAIN TO VIEW THE CO-EFFICIENT FOR THE CHOSEN MODEL ===")
```

Below is the output of the method most_informative_feature_for_binary_classification:

When the program first run (it will show classes 2 and 3 informative feature):

```
2 -8.322094697329087 aaa
2 -8.322094697329087 aaa cm
2 -8.322094697329087 aaa cm underwent
2 -8.322094697329087 aaa free
2 -8.322094697329087 aaa free ivc

3 -8.010764835561018 assymetry imp giddiness
3 -8.144858449457846 admitted feb year
3 -8.164330364141858 agreeable dre brown
3 -8.172447581146958 aerobic anaerobic labeled
3 -8.180391164585233 actually body
```

When the program run the second time (it will show classes 3 and 4 informative feature):

```
3 -8.322580751462969 aaa
3 -8.322580751462969 aaa cm
3 -8.322580751462969 aaa cm underwent
3 -8.322580751462969 aaa free
3 -8.322580751462969 aaa free ivc

4 -8.0112508896949 assymetry moving
4 -8.145344503591728 admitted feb year
4 -8.16481641827574 agreeable dre brown
4 -8.17293363528084 aerobic anaerobic labeled
4 -8.180877218719115 actually body
```

When the program run the third time (it will show classes 4 and 5 informative feature):

```
4 -8.322337753927105 aaa
4 -8.322337753927105 aaa cm
4 -8.322337753927105 aaa cm underwent
4 -8.322337753927105 aaa free
4 -8.322337753927105 aaa free ivc

5 -8.011007892159036 assymetry imp
5 -8.145101506055864 admitted frequent falls
5 -8.164573420739876 agreeable early review
5 -8.172690637744976 af anticoagulation
5 -8.18063422118325 actually body
```

If you guys realize the above results, they are all the same. Please help me check the codes for the most_informative_feature_binary_classification method codes. Thanks :((

Example of counter.json:

```
1
```

Below are the classifiers that have made use of the most_informative_feature_binary_classification method:

Naive bayes classifier:

```
def NB_func():

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df['content'], df['cat_id'], random_state=0)
    count_vect = CountVectorizer()
    X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(X_train)
    tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
    X_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts)
    clf_NB = MultinomialNB().fit(X_train_tfidf, y_train)

    # save the model to disk
    filename = '../dataanalysis/models/Naive_Bayes.sav'
    pickle.dump(clf_NB, open(filename, 'wb'))

    print()
    '''Print the prediction of the category from the unknown document'''
    #For now its not accurate due to insufficient sample data
    #print("NAIVE BAYES CLASSIFIER: ", clf_NB.predict(count_vect.transform([""])))
    print ()

    print("===============================================")
    print("================= NAIVE BAYES =================")
    print("===============================================")
    most_informative_feature_for_binary_classification(tfidf, clf_NB, n=5)
```

Logistic Regression classifier:

```
def LR_func():

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df['content'], df['cat_id'], random_state=0)
    count_vect = CountVectorizer()
    X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(X_train)
    tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
    X_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts)
    clf_LR = LogisticRegression().fit(X_train_tfidf, y_train)

    print()
    '''Print the prediction of the category from the unknown document'''
    #For now its not accurate due to insufficient sample data
    #print("LOGISTICS REGRESSION CLASSIFIER: ", clf_LR.predict(count_vect.transform([""])))
    print ()

    # save the model to disk
    filename = '../dataanalysis/models/Logistics_Regression.sav'
    pickle.dump(clf_LR, open(filename, 'wb'))

    print()

    print("===============================================")
    print("============ LOGISTICS REGRESSION =============")
    print("===============================================")
    most_informative_feature_for_binary_classification(tfidf, clf_LR, n=5)
```

Comment: 1. Fix the indent of your code block. My _guess_ is that the entire thing is one function `most_informative_feature_for_binary_classification`. 2. Post a sample of your `counter.json` file. 3. This has nothing to do with [tag:sharepoint], remove that tag.

Comment: I have posted a sample of the counter.json whenever the program runs, for instance, the program ran twice: what is shown in the counter.json will actually be the number of times the program has executed @aneroid

Comment: @aneroid I have fixed the indentation of my code block but still could not work :(( still prints out the same result...

Comment: Wouldn't know without seeing what `classifier` you're using. What value of `n` are calling it with? If `sorted(zip(classifier.coef_[0], feature_names))` is a small list, then `l[:100]` and `l[-100:]` will give the same result so `topn_class1` and `topn_class2` will also be the same. The words in each of the first sections are the same but the `coef`s are different. In the second section of each print, the `coef`s and `feat`s are different. Not sure how much difference you were expecting.

Comment: @aneroid if u see the print out the first of every class is always the same results but they are of the different classes it should not have the same result...

Comment: @aneroid I have added the classifiers that have made use of the most_informative_feature_binary_classification method. Please take a look at my codes, thank you!!

Comment: You can avoid all that if/else simply by deriving the indices to `class_labels` using `counter`... Reducing the number of lines of code makes it easier to read and hence easier to spot potential mistakes.

Comment: @lightalchemist could you show me the examples of how should I derive the indices to the class_labels using coutner?

Comment: @School What I meant to say was: assume `l = sorted(zip(classifier.coef_[0], feature_names))`. If `n >= len(l)`, then `l[:n]` and `l[-n:]` will always be equal; as will `topn_class1` and `topn_class2`. What is the output of `len(sorted(zip(classifier.coef_[0], feature_names)))` and what `n` value are you using? _(In your update, I see `n=5`.)_ If you're trying to create a growing list of `topn_class1 & 2`, then use `counter` instead of `n` when you slice the sorted list. Otherwise, they are always the same regardless of `counter`. So each time you loop, it has the same features.

Comment: @aneroid  Then is there a way to make the results different for the different classes

Comment: @School `print(class_labels[counter - 1], coef, feat)` for the first `for` loop and `print(class_labels[counter], coef, feat)` for the second one. So you don't need the various if/else clause just to customize these 2 indices.

Comment: `classifier` is always the same for a given `vectorizer`. Running it multiple times wouldn't give different results (except for `n`) unless the model keeps getting retrained.

Comment: @aneroid is it possible if i do the for loop in the classifiers because each classes have different results and i would like to show different results for each different classes

Comment: @lightalchemist could u kindly edit my codes or copy and paste my codes to show me (because 6 counters for the for loops), thanks :((

Comment: Maybe do a `print(clf_NB.classes_)` and `print(clf_LR._classes_)`  inside the classifier functions. But since it's the same input state and random state each time you execute, no difference will occur there. (Side note: I have edited your question with the "1 loop instead of 6" change.)